# Python: Regex needed

Tags: python, regex

This is probably simple, but I can't figure this out:
I need regex expression which would extract following records (Each record may span multiple lines and delimited by one or more blank lines):

TextTextTextTextTextTextText

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText

(one or more blank lines)

TextTextTextTextText

TextTextText

TextTextTextTextTextTextText

(one or more blank lines)

TextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText

Comment: Either solution posted so far (Can's or Eli's) will work but you'll probably want to do a .strip() on each of the items returned, and also skip empty strings as you iterate (for cases like quadruple-or-more blank lines, leading/trailing blank lines etc).

Comment: My solution doesn't generate empty strings or leading/trailing blank lines.

Comment: @Can, sure it does, if the text starts with a newline, for example.  Or if it ends with two or more newlines.  It's trivial to test: `re.split(r'\n\n+', '''\ntext\n\ntext\n\n''')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
re.split('\n\n+', text)
```